# Arrange Flex-Items

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Let's say I have a Flex-Box #X in which i want to arrange 4 Flex-Items #Y1 ... #Y4 as follows:
[image: Positioning]
For an output medium smaller than 60em the flex-items should be positioned like this:
[image: Position2]

I know what i have to do for the HTML part, but what do i have to do for the css part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean like this? The example works with media query and `flex-direction: column-reverse;`.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  background: gray;
  justify-content: space-between;
  gap:10px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding:10px;
  max-width: 900px;
}

.item {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width:100%;
  max-width:400px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  height:100px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .flex {
    flex-direction: column-reverse;   
  }  
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="item">A</div>
  <div class="item">B</div>
  <div class="item">C</div>
  <div class="item">D</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes exactly thank you very much. The boxes of the flex-items are quite big though

Comment: @Dennis You welcome! with the item max-witdth you can adjust the size. play around and find it out what suits you.